# The difference between Express.js and koa2.js when handling asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, async-await, koa

I have following code to set the router using express and it works fine:

```
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    queries.getAll().then(stickers=>{
        res.json(stickers)
    })
})
```

`queries.getAll()` is a function that will do the MySQL query and get the stickers data I need. However, when I use koa2 to write something similar, it won't work:

```
router.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
    queries.getAll().then(stickers=>{
    ctx.body = JSON.stringify(stickers)
    })
}
```

As far as I know, I have to put "await" before the query function, like this:

```
await queries.getAll().then(stickers=>{
ctx.body = JSON.stringify(stickers)
})
```

So that means in Koa2 you have to wait until MySQL query is finished and then send the result to client. Otherwise nothing will be sent. However, it seems like in Express the result will be automatically sent as soon as the query is finished. Why is that? 
Maybe I am missing some fundamentals about Nodejs. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

koa allows you to leverage async functions unlike express which works with callbacks. if you want to await database queries, then the await expression has to be within an async function.

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  let res = await queries.getAll();
  res.then(
    //do stuff
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question is more about understanding `async` functions, than about the nuances of express and koa.

First of all take a look at the docs for [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which returns an AsyncFunction object. An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously via the event loop, using an implicit Promise to return its result. But the syntax and structure of your code using async functions is much more like using standard synchronous functions.

`async` functions are like syntactic sugar: whenever there is an `await` operator, the function execution 'freezes' and continues when the `Promise` resolves. Under the hood it works similarly to callbacks, but the code is more readable.

The docs for [`await` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) states:

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a Promise is resolved, that is fulfilled or rejected, and to resume execution of the async function after fulfillment. When resumed, the value of the await expression is that of the fulfilled Promise.

So for Koa your code should look like this:

```
router.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = await queries.getAll();
  })
}
```

It works like this:

- `queries.getAll()` returns a `Promise`;
- `await` pauses function execution until the `Promise` resolves or rejects;
- when the `Promise` resolves, `await` extracts resolved value and returns it to `ctx.body`;
- koa will automatically encode data to JSON as it is stated in the [docs](https://koajs.com/#response):

> response.body=
>
> Set response body to one of the following:
>
> string written
>
> Buffer written
>
> Stream piped
>
> Object || Array json-stringified
>
> null no content response
>
> If response.status has not been set, Koa will automatically set the status to 200 or 204.

Also keep in mind that `await` does not pause the whole app, it pauses only the execution of the specific function and if during this pause any event occurs, it will be processed.